# Why does my error not show up in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to set up custom error handling in a SharePoint site.
But I have no idea how this works.

So I have set up a bare bones SharePoint Project with just an Event Receiver for an Announcement list to play with.

On itemAdded for an Announcement type list, I just append some text to the title and see it happen.  Now I try to add:

```
throw new Exception("There was a problem with the operation with the operation.")
```

or 
    throw new SpException("There was a problem with the operation with the operation.")

so when I debug and attach to a site at
    http://[exampleMachineName]/Dev1 siteCollection,

go to the announcments list and add a listItem, the debugger stops at the offending line throwing the exception.

Now, when I hit F11 or Green Arrow (Continue) I would expect to see the yellow screen showing my error message or a default error screen from SharePoint.

But I see neither, it just continues on and shows my new List Item on the Announcements List.

In custom ASP.Net Web Forms or MVC I would see the yellow screen, or HTTP 500 or something.
What is happening under the hood here and how to I replicate a yellow screen of death situation like I am trying to solve in our real application.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the type of event receive that you've created - ItemAdded is asynchronous event receiver so it fires after item already added to list and if some unhandled error appears in this receiver then no error in you http page occurs.It writes error message in ULS logs though. 
Try to use ItemAdding event receiver.

Comment: Oh - thanks, that works.
Now I get a popup Error dialog with the text of message from the SPexception I threw.

So now I am wondering why my project I am playing with does this but our real application gives the yellow screen.  Could this be the Custom Errors setting somewhere. Could they have turned this off?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely custom error section set in web config, Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231550.aspx. You need to set customErrors mode="On".

Comment: Also don't forget to do issreset after change web.config.

Comment: Thanks again. Being a SharePoint newbie, I am wondering which web.config to change this in. The hive, or in the actual web application for IIS at inetpub/wwwroot/wss/virtualdirectories/[port number].  So what is the difference between these two and are there any more hiding anywhere.  This is totally different from my ASP.Net experience where you have a hierarchy of web.config(s) and machine.config.

Comment: You need to change web config in web application - inetpub/wwwroot/wss/virtualdirectories/[port number]